# User closes the browser without logging out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, social-networking

I am developing a social network in ASP.NET MVC 3. Every user has must have the ability to see connected people.

What is the best way to do this?

I added a flag in the table `Contact` in my database, and I set it to `true` when the user logs in and set it to `false` when he logs out.

But the problem with this solution is when the user closes the browser without logging out, he will still remain connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to truly know that a user is currently connected is to maintain some sort of connection between the user and the server.  Two options immediately come to mind:

1. Use javascript to periodically call your server using ajax. You would have a special endpoint on your server that would be used to update a "last connected time" status, and you would have a second endpoint for users to poll to see who is online.
2. Use a [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) to maintain a persistent connection with your server

Option 1 should be fairly easy to implement.  The main thing to keep in mind that this will increase the amount of requests coming into your server, and you will have to plan accordingly in order handle the traffic this could generate.  You will have some control over the amount of load on your server by configuring how often javascript timer calls back to your server.

Option 2 could be a little more involved if you did this without library support.  Of course there are libraries out there such as [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) that make this really easy to do.  This also has an impact on the performance of your site since each user will be maintaining a persistent connection.  The advantage with this approach is that it reduces the need for polling like option 1 does.  If you use this approach it would also be very easy to push a message to user A that user B has gone offline.

I guess I should also mention a really easy 3rd option as well.  If you feel like your site is pretty interactive, you could just track the last time they made a request to your site.  This of course may not give you enough accuracy to determine whether a user is "connected".

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for all these details, option 2 seems to be the best choice. I will try to implement it.